# Moving ttf file causes extra extension

Tags: sh, mv

I rename my files after compression for the negotiation to occur correctly. One of the commands used is

```
find dist -name "*.ttf" -type f -print -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv -- "$f" "${f%.ttf}.ttf.ttf"' \;
```

The same command works perfectly fine for html, css, svg, etc extensions and results in files with double extensions as expected. eg - <>.html.html

But, the above command results in .ttf.ttf.ttf

I am running this as part of gitlab CI which generates a fresh build. So, there is no chance of conflict as it starts from an empty folder altogether.
This is done for serving compressed files for a static site. The server is Apache and I cannot find anything in the httpd.conf or .htaccess that might be additionally renaming the file.

Expected output - *.ttf files should be renamed to *.ttf.ttf

Comment: `find` isn't guaranteed to first identify all `ttf` files, then rename them; it's finding one, renaming it, then moving on to the next one. As a result, it's finding "additional" `ttf` files to rename after the original ones have *already* been renamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid race conditions and other implementation-specific obstacles, do this in two steps. First, rename each file with a "marker":

```
find dist -name "*.ttf" -type f -print -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%.ttf}.ttf.foo"' _ {} \;
```

then replace the "marker"  with the proper extension:

```
find dist -name "*.foo" -type f -print -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%.foo}.ttf"' _ {} \;
```

This guarantees that `find` cannot create a file with the same extension that it is processing.

Comment: This worked for me. But I just find it curious that this issue showed up only for ttf files. Why not the same issue for js/html/php files which I am running the same command for as well.